# How to generate Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I want to generate the javadoc in eclipse but I don't have the file `C:\JBuilderX\jdk1.8\bin\javadoc.exe`. for the command path. Please help!

Comment: Download it from web?

Comment: Where else on your system do you have javadoc.exe?

Comment: `javadoc` is part of JDK.

Comment: I don't have javadoc.exe on my system and I didn't find a link where to download the javadoc.exe.

Comment: @Elysium check your `$JDK_HOME/bin/` and add it to the path.

Comment: I did check my jdk_home/bin/ and I don't have the javadoc.exe file

Comment: I know that javadoc is part of jdk..but I miss that file. And I don't understand why

Comment: Might I suggest installing the latest JDK, which by default is installed under C:\Program Files\Java, then replacing your apparently compromised JDK with a copy of the new installation?

Comment: @VGR Yes.. you were right but I didn't expect that from the oracle installer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try *JAutoDoc*, it's quite simple and easy to use:

1. Go to *Help*->*Eclipse Marketplace*
2. In *Find* editext write **jautodoc** , then click on *GO*.
3. Install the javadocs and restart Eclipse.
4. To use these docs, right click on class and click on *JAutoDoc* .

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I didn't asked for that.